# IBM Tivoli Access manager on 64 bit windows

Tags: tivoli

From what I can tell there is no 64 bit version of IBM Tivoli Access Manager.

How can I integrate Tivoli Access Manager API  with my 64 bit native windows application application?

Will Tivoli Access Manager API work with a 64 bit CLR application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly it is beyond the means of a small company like IBM to recompile the source code for 64 bit.

Their official advice is to create a 32bit web service using the 32 bit Tivoli Access Manager Assemblies and call that from the 64 bit code.

Lame.